# Using an LSTM model with 2 simultaneous signals to denoise one of the signals

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, signal-processing

in the medical imaging field, it is common to have two signals, where artifact in one signal bleeds into the other. I'm exploring whether a deep learning model can be used with these signals to regress out the artifact (this is for a student project and for my own curiosity).

Here is a grossly oversimplified example: We are given two signals, signal_X, and signal_Y. Signal_X is a flat line with an occasional square wave pulse. Signal_Y is a pure sine wave. When signal_X pulses, it leaks into signal_Y such that signal_Y's amplitude increases. We consider this to be artifact.

**The goal is to use an LSTM model to learn the relationship between signal_X and signal_Y, so that we can regress out the "noise" injected into signal_Y when signal_X pulses.**

Below I am training the model on (x,y) pairs from signal_X and signal_Y. Then I fit that model to signal_X itself to get predicted values. I then define the corrected signal_Y as

`corrected_signal_Y =  Y_train - pred_Y`

The result isn't great, but I feel that I may be way off base here. ***Am I actually just training my model to predict signal_Y (artifact included)? If so, then my calculation of "corrected_Y" must be conceptually wrong.***

## Minimal working example

You can see use the code below, or just run it in [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iW0xeg43NAc7CajEKGY_rqMHELc_T_pe?usp=sharing)

YOU CAN SKIP THIS: This first code block is just to generate the signals

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def simulate_signals(N, sine_amplitude, sine_frequency, square_amplitude, square_duration, pulse_prob):
  """simulate a square wave (signal X) and a sine wave (signal Y)


  Parameters
  ----------
  N : int
    the length of the signals, in samples.
  sin_amplitude: int | float
    The amplitude of the sine wave
  sine_frequency: int
    Frequency of the sine wave
  square_amplitude : int
    Amplitude of the artifact square wave in signal Y
  square_duration: int
    Duration of the artifact square wave in signal Y
  pulse_prob: float
    Probability of a square wave pulse occurring in signal X at each time step

  Returns
  -------
  Signal_X, signal_Y
  """
  # Generate time axis
  t = np.arange(N)

  # Simulate signal X with occasional square wave pulses
  signal_X = np.zeros(N)
  for i in range(N):
      if np.random.rand() < pulse_prob:
          signal_X[i:i+square_duration] = 1

  # Simulate signal Y as a pure sine wave with added artifact square wave component
  signal_Y_sine = sine_amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * sine_frequency * t)
  signal_Y_square = square_amplitude * signal_X
  signal_Y = signal_Y_sine + signal_Y_square

  return signal_X, signal_Y

# Parameters for the simulation
N = 1000
sine_amplitude = 1.0
sine_frequency = 0.05
square_amplitude = 0.5
square_duration = 20
pulse_prob = 0.02

# Simulate signals X and Y
signal_X, signal_Y = simulate_signals(N, sine_amplitude, sine_frequency,
                                      square_amplitude, square_duration,
                                      pulse_prob)

# Plot the signals
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(signal_X, label='Signal X')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(0, 1000)


plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(signal_Y, label='Signal Y')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(0, 1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Image of signal_X and signal_Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDQij.png)

THIS IS THE CODE BLOCK WITH THE MODEL

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, LSTM

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


scaler = StandardScaler()
# normalize, add empty dimension, downsample by factor of 10
X = scaler.fit_transform(signal_X.reshape(-1, 1))
Y = scaler.fit_transform(signal_Y.reshape(-1, 1))
print(f"X, Y shape: {X.shape}, {Y.shape}")

nb_time = 100
n_blocks = 50
step = 10
model = Sequential()


# Split dataset
n = int(X.shape[0] / nb_time) # i.e 1000 / 100
X_train = X[:nb_time * n, :].reshape((-1, nb_time, X.shape[-1]), order='C')
Y_train = Y[:nb_time * n, :].reshape((-1, nb_time, Y.shape[-1]), order='C')


# LSTM layer accepts a 3D array as input which has a shape of (n_sample, n_timesteps, n_features)
model.add(LSTM(n_blocks, input_shape=(nb_time,  X_train.shape[-1]),
               return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(Y.shape[1],
               return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))


# try this optimizer instead of 'adam'
adagrad = tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=1)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adagrad)
print(model.summary())


model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=50,
          validation_split=0.2, batch_size=1, verbose=2)


# Visualize loss
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(model.history.history["loss"], label="Training Loss") # blue
ax.plot(model.history.history["val_loss"], label="Validation Loss") # orange
plt.legend()
```

[Visualization of the Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1zmB.png)

```py
# Make predictions
predicted_Y = model.predict(X_train)

# Deno[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECfJP.png)rmalize predictions
predicted_Y_denormalized = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_Y.reshape(-1, 1))

# Correct the signal: I'm unsure whether this is conceptually correct
corrected_signal_Y = Y_train.reshape((-1,1)) - predicted_Y_denormalized

# Plot original signal_Y and predicted signal_Y
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax.plot(Y_train.reshape((-1,1)), label='Original Signal Y')
ax.plot(predicted_Y_denormalized, label='Predicted Signal Y')
ax.plot(corrected_signal_Y, label="Corrected Signal_Y")
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Plot of signal_Y, pred_Y, and corrected_Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCgmR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to supply the square wave `signal_X` and the noised signal `signal_Y` as input features (or just one of those, if you prefer). Use the clean signal `signal_Y_sine` as the target. The model should learn to reproduce the clean signal from the input feature(s).

[image]

```
signal_X, signal_Y, signal_Y_target = simulate_signals(...)

# Plot the signals
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2.5))
ax.plot(signal_X, 'r-', lw=1.3, label='signal_X')
ax.plot(signal_Y, 'tab:green', lw=1.3, label='signal_Y')
ax.plot(signal_Y_target, lw=2, color='tab:brown', label='Target: signal_Y_sine')
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax.set_xlabel('n')
f.legend(loc='upper center', ncol=3)
```

Comment: Interesting. This follows a framework of some [previous models](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/signal-denoising-using-adversarial-learning-denoiser-model.html), in which you use a "clean" version of the signal to train your algorithm. Sometimes a ground-truth clean signal isn't available, which is the motivation to create a model in the first place. I think using a metric like the signal-to-noise ratio could be an alternative.